# Save only modified elements of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular

I am working with Angular, C# for the backend and DB with Oracle. The project is for a company and in the grids they leave me more than 120 records. In these grids the user can edit each record and by selecting the "Save" button all the records are sent (those that have been modified and those that have not been modified) and that is where I need your help. How can you tell which records have changed? MY IDEA is to make a copy of the data that arrives and at the end compare which ones have been changed and send that new list to the database (only with the changed records). ANOTHER IDEA is that every time someone makes a change, it will be added to another list, but the problem with this is how to identify when it changes and when it changes and returns to how it was ... Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using angular forms? Can you show some code as well. Angular form API has properties like dirty/pristine etc. which can tell you which fields are modified.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to keep track of which elements have been modified:

- Define an interface with the object *and* an "isModified" flag. As each item is modified, turn that flag to true.
- Keep a separate list of modified objects (as you mentioned)
- Keep a list of the Ids of the modified objects

With regard to how to determine whether an object has been changed, that will depend on how you are handling the edits. If you are using Angular Forms (as mentioned by @nobalG above), then it will tell you went the data is modified.

If not, again depending on how you are handling the edits, you may have other `changed` events you can track.

More detail isn't possible without having some code detailing how you are handling the edits.